# How to set parent for datastrore entity during bulkloading data by appcfg.py on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, bulk-load

I'm trying to bulkload data using appcfg.py as described [here](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Creating_Loader_Classes). I got it working except setting parent entity, I can't  seem to find info on how to set a parent entity for entity being created by the import. Can you point me to the right direction or provide a code snippet for my bulkloader.Loader implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the generate_key method of your Loader class. See [this post](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Advanced-Bulk-Loading-part-2-Customization) for details.

Comment: There is no example on how to set parent in that post :(

Comment: Just return the key you want your entity to have from the generate_key function. You can construct it with, eg, db.Key.from_path('kind', 'name', parent=parent_key)