# Uploading entity with parent using bulkloader

Tags: google-app-engine, parent, bulkloader

So, I am trying to create an entity with a parent using bulkloader.

I have a Client entity:

```
class Client(db.Model):
    identifier = db.StringProperty()
    www_ip = db.StringProperty()
    local_ip = db.StringProperty()
    status=db.BooleanProperty()
```

And I want to create a Data entiy as child of Client.

```
class Data(db.Model):
    songscount = db.IntegerProperty()
    nextorder = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    players = db.ListProperty(str)
    previousplayer = db.StringProperty()
```

Client entity exists.
Data.yaml is (without preamble):

```
transformers:
- kind: Data
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      import_transform: transform.create_deep_key(('Client', '__key__'), ('Data', transform.CURRENT_PROPERTY))
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: nextorder
      external_name: nextorder
      import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(int)

    - property: players
      external_name: players
      import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(users.User)  # Assumes email address

    - property: previousplayer
      external_name: previousplayer
      import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(users.User)  # Assumes email address

    - property: songscount
      external_name: songscount
      import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(int)
```

I understand that either transform.create_foreign_key or transform.create_deep_key needs to be used. What I dont understand is how to inform about my Client entity (which is parent).

I found one such question discussed [How to set parent for datastrore entity during bulkloading data by appcfg.py on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356158/how-to-set-parent-for-datastrore-entity-during-bulkloading-data-by-appcfg-py-on) , but 'Code configuration' has been deprecated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but for future reference, it seems the answer is here:

```
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      import_transform: transform.create_deep_key(('clientKey‘, ‘clientKey‘),(’key‘, transform.CURRENT_PROPERTY))
      export:
      - external_name: clientKey
        export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string_n(0)
      - external_name: key
        export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string_n(1)
```

(adapted from http://longsystemit.com/javablog/?p=23)